# hubotからdiscordへメッセージを送りたい

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, hubot

hubotからdiscordへmessageを送りたいのですが、
envelopeの指定がslackなどへ送信するときと違うのか、上手くいかないです。

node.js/coffescriptに慣れておらず、debug方法なども曖昧なところもあり、
良い解決方法があればご教授ください。

Adapterにはhubot-discordを利用しています

・コード

```
cronJob = require('cron').CronJob

module.exports = (robot) ->
  cronjob = new cronJob('0 1-59 * * * *', () =>
    envelope = room: "#channel"
    robot.send envelope, "cron テスト@all"
  )
  cronjob.start()
```

・エラー

```
ERROR { Error: Could not resolve channel
  at Resolver.resolveChannel (/home/user/git/appname/node_modules/discord.js/lib/Client/Resolver/Resolver.js:34:51)
  at InternalClient.sendMessage (/home/user/git/appname/node_modules/discord.js/lib/Client/InternalClient.js:32:25)
  at Client.sendMessage (/home/user/git/appname/node_modules/discord.js/lib/Client/Client.js:137:54)
  at DiscordBot.send (/home/user/git/appname/node_modules/hubot-discord/src/discord.coffee:76:13, <js>:117:30)
  at Robot.send (/home/user/git/appname/node_modules/hubot/src/robot.coffee:542:19, <js>:432:42)
  at CronJob.<anonymous> (/home/user/git/appname/scripts/daily.coffee:11:5, <js>:17:20)
  at CronJob.fireOnTick (/home/user/git/appname/node_modules/cron/lib/cron.js:422:22)
  at Timeout.callbackWrapper [as _onTimeout] (/home/user/git/appname/node_modules/cron/lib/cron.js:487:9)
  at ontimeout (timers.js:471:11)
  at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:306:5)
  at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:266:5)
 resource: undefined }
```

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すみません、こちら解決しました。。。
discordではchannel名はidを利用するようでした。

console.log(responseobject)で中身を確認することができましたmm